# Nand2Tetris-project5, Error: No such built-in chip used: RAM16K

Tags: hdl, nand2tetris

When I am testing the computer.hdl through computerAdd.tst script, my Hardware Simulator shows me the error: No such built-in chip used: RAM16K, but I have already copied the RAM16K chip.hdl into such folder. Anyone knows why?

Computer.hdl:

```
CHIP Computer {

    IN reset;

    PARTS:
    // Put your code here:
    ROM32K(address=pc, out=instruction);
    CPU(inM=inM, instruction=instruction, reset=reset, outM=outM, writeM=writeM, addressM=addressM, pc=pc);
    Memory(in=outM, load=writeM, address=addressM, out=inM);
}
```

computerAdd.tst:

```
load Computer.hdl,
output-file ComputerAdd.out,
compare-to ComputerAdd.cmp,
output-list time%S1.4.1 reset%B2.1.2 ARegister[0]%D1.7.1 DRegister[0]%D1.7.1 PC[]%D0.4.0 RAM16K[0]%D1.7.1 RAM16K[1]%D1.7.1 RAM16K[2]%D1.7.1;

// Load a program written in the Hack machine language.
// The program adds the two constants 2 and 3 and writes the result in RAM[0]. 
ROM32K load Add.hack,
output;

// First run (at the beginning PC=0)
repeat 6 {
    tick, tock, output;
}

// Reset the PC
set reset 1,
set RAM16K[0] 0,
tick, tock, output;


// Second run, to check that the PC was reset correctly.
set reset 0,

repeat 6 {
    tick, tock, output;
}
```

computerAdd.cmp:

```
| time |reset|ARegister|DRegister|PC[]|RAM16K[0]|RAM16K[1]|RAM16K[2]|
| 0    |  0  |       0 |       0 |   0|       0 |       0 |       0 |
| 1    |  0  |       2 |       0 |   1|       0 |       0 |       0 |
| 2    |  0  |       2 |       2 |   2|       0 |       0 |       0 |
| 3    |  0  |       3 |       2 |   3|       0 |       0 |       0 |
| 4    |  0  |       3 |       5 |   4|       0 |       0 |       0 |
| 5    |  0  |       0 |       5 |   5|       0 |       0 |       0 |
| 6    |  0  |       0 |       5 |   6|       5 |       0 |       0 |
| 7    |  1  |       0 |       5 |   0|       0 |       0 |       0 |
| 8    |  0  |       2 |       5 |   1|       0 |       0 |       0 |
| 9    |  0  |       2 |       2 |   2|       0 |       0 |       0 |
| 10   |  0  |       3 |       2 |   3|       0 |       0 |       0 |
| 11   |  0  |       3 |       5 |   4|       0 |       0 |       0 |
| 12   |  0  |       0 |       5 |   5|       0 |       0 |       0 |
| 13   |  0  |       0 |       5 |   6|       5 |       0 |       0 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to be sure, but as far as I know, you don't "copy the RAM16K chip.hdl into such folder" (I think you are referring to the tools/builtInChips folder?)

RAM16K (and Memory) are built-in chips. If you mess with the definitions in the builtInChips folder, weirdness will ensue.

Similarly, if you have copied your RAM16K.hdl file (or other subcomponent hdl files) into the folder containing your Computer.hdl, this could interfere with the simulator finding the correct chip implementation. Try deleting those files.